# Was George Lucas involved at all in The Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, george-lucas

George Lucas has famously sold Lucasfilm to Disney, but has he still had some sort of involvement in the production of *Star Wars: The Force Awakens*?

For example, as a:

- consultant
- scriptwriter
- producer
- other

**What involvement did George Lucas have with *The Force Awakens*?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Creative consultant only

George Lucas sold his LucasArts production company — including the entire *Star Wars* franchise — to Disney Entertainment in 2012.  This was prior to any production on *The Force Awakens*.  In fact, it was this move that led to planning for a new trilogy.

George Lucas remains a "creative consultant" on all Disney-era *Star Wars* film projects, but this is a fairly amorphous role.  For instance, he submitted rough story ideas for new *Star Wars* episodes to Disney.  These  were summarily [rejected by the new film's director, J.J. Abrams, and producer Kathleen Kennedy](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/Why-Disney-Didn-t-Want-George-Lucas-Star-Wars-7-Ideas-71376.html).  In the end, Michael Arndt, Lawrence Kasdan, and J.J. Abrams conceived the story for *The Force Awakens* without any input from Lucas.

Apparently, George was ["happy not to be involved"](http://screenrant.com/star-wars-7-force-awakens-george-lucas-role/).  Early in 2015, he said:

> "I haven’t seen anything; I mean I saw the trailer, it looks great, it looks interesting. But as I’ve said before: one thing I regret about *Star Wars* is that I never got to see it, you know? I never got to be blown away by the big ship coming over the thing, or anything. **But this time I’m going to be, because I have no idea what they’re doing.**"

All in all, he really had no measurable role in the film — apart from the fact that *The Force Awakens* is really uncomfortably close in plot to his original 1977 *Star Wars* film.  In that sense, he contributed *a lot* to *The Force Awakens*.

Comment: How can he possibly be blown away by something new if all they did was carbon-copy Episodes 4-6? :)))

Comment: @DVK : Indeed...

Comment: @DVK The statement was from _early_ 2015, I wonder what he said _after_ actually having watched it...

Comment: @Zommuter : He stated a few days ago that he doesn't much care for *The Force Awakens*, saying it is [too "retro"](http://www.theguardian.com/film/2015/dec/31/george-lucas-attacks-retro-star-wars-the-force-awakens) for his tastes.

Comment: @Praxis "retro" pretty much sums it up indeed. Though personally I wouldn't say _too_ retro, it _was_ nice to watch, but yes, there were no real surprises...

Comment: Indeed, must George L. has been blown away by the new episode; not by the quality of the movie itself but by how much they plagiarised his movies 4-6.  Now, the next big question is: what will they do plagiarise from the ep. 1-3 for the next movie(s)?  Secondly, beeing officially a Creative Consultant is some kind of a double-edged sword: George L. can submit ideas to Disney but at the same time, probably that he is forbidden by a confidential agreement to reveal anything about these new ideas; so I wonder if we will ever know anything about what was his personal ideas for the next trilogy.

Comment: http://www.rollingstone.com/movies/news/george-lucas-apologizes-over-force-awakens-criticisms-20160101 and http://news.yahoo.com/george-lucas-explains-why-didn-t-star-wars-153745258.html?nf=1 are what @Praxis is referring to, I think. :)

Comment: It's not plagiarism.  They rhyme. :P

Comment: @SylvainL - ep 1-3 don't exist. And if a single frame of last jedi resembles anything from those non-existent jokes, neither will ep 8.